# A mistake paste in shell cause CPU load going very high and then out of control

Tags: linux, shell

Today I pasted a string into my linux shell by mistake, after that CPU load went  very high and then it got out of control

my environment is CentOS 6.5, and the string I paste is a json formated request log:

```
[{"timestamp":1487240104178,"info":{"method":"GET","path":"/APIService/v1/refreshSession","headers":{"request":{"user-agent":"curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2","host":"172.22.3.12:8122","accept":"*/*"},"response":{"X-Application-Context":"application:8122","status":"404"}}}},{"timestamp":1487240077403,"info":{"method":"GET","path":"/APIService/v1/refreshSession","headers":{"request":{"user-agent":"curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2","host":"172.22.3.12:8122","accept":"*/*"},"response":{"X-Application-Context":"application:8122","status":"404"}}}},{"timestamp":1487240075185,"info":{"method":"GET","path":"/APIService/v1/refreshSession","headers":{"request":{"user-agent":"curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2","host":"172.22.3.12:8122","accept":"*/*"},"response":{"X-Application-Context":"application:8122","status":"404"}}}},{"timestamp":1487240050994,"info":{"method":"GET","path":"/APIService/v1/refreshSession","headers":{"request":{"user-agent":"curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2","host":"172.22.3.12:8122","accept":"*/*"},"response":{"X-Application-Context":"application:8122","status":"404"}}}},{"timestamp":1487240037110,"info":{"method":"GET","path":"/APIService/v1/refreshSession","headers":{"request":{"user-agent":"curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2","host":"172.22.3.12:8122","accept":"*/*"},"response":{"X-Application-Context":"application:8122","status":"404"}}}},{"timestamp":1487240025956,"info":{"method":"GET","path":"/APIService/v1/refreshSession","headers":{"request":{"user-agent":"curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2","host":"172.22.3.12:8122","accept":"*/*"},"response":{"X-Application-Context":"application:8122","status":"404"}}}},{"timestamp":1487239999461,"info":{"method":"GET","path":"/APIService/v1/refreshSession","headers":{"request":{"host":"172.22.1.15","remote_addr":"172.22.1.15","x-real-ip":"172.22.1.15","x-forwarded-for":"172.22.1.15","user-agent":"curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2","accept":"*/*"},"response":{"X-Application-Context":"application:8122","status":"404"}}}},{"timestamp":1487239998662,"info":{"method":"GET","path":"/APIService/v1/refreshSession","headers":{"request":{"host":"172.22.1.15","remote_addr":"172.22.1.15","x-real-ip":"172.22.1.15","x-forwarded-for":"172.22.1.15","user-agent":"curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2","accept":"*/*"},"response":{"X-Application-Context":"application:8122","status":"404"}}}},{"timestamp":1487239889129,"info":{"method":"GET","path":"/APIservice/v1/refreshSession","headers":{"request":{"host":"172.22.1.15","remote_addr":"172.22.1.15","x-real-ip":"172.22.1.15","x-forwarded-for":"172.22.1.15","user-agent":"curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2","accept":"*/*"},"response":{"X-Application-Context":"application:8122","status":"404"}}}}][root@web-01 conf]
```

after reboot, the machine is ok.

Can anybody tell me what happened, why that string caused such high CPU load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `[root@web-01 conf]` at the end of the string.  Is that a shell prompt?  Are you logged in to a shell as root?  I slap your wrists!  Don't do that.

I'm not certain, but I believe the shell is trying to expand the string into a command, and hitting a wall because of the multiple occurrences of the string `*/*`.  When bash sees a string of the form `{a,b,c,*/*}`, it attempts to expand it to the string `a b c ...` where `...` is a the expansion of the glob `*/*`.  When it sees nested bracket expansions, it expands them as well.  I think you've got a combinatorial explosion happening.